# Omnifaces o:messages rendering with custom message

Tags: validation, jsf, message, omnifaces

In Omnifaces it's possible to render messages on your own, using `<o:messages var="msg">`, but this only works if you use the `var` attribute. If you specify a custom message with `message` attribute in combination with `var` attribute, all messages will be displayed instead of the custom one.
Is it possible to render custom message on your own in any way?

### Example

This

```html
<o:messages var="msg" for="form">
    <div>#{msg.summary}</div>
</o:messages>
```

renders as

```html
<div>form:select: Validation Error: Value is required.</div>
```

What I would like to do is render this:

```html
<o:messages var="msg" for="form" message="Error!">
    <div>#{msg.summary}</div>
</o:messages>
```

as:

```html
<div>Error!</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you just put `<div>Error!</div>` directly under `<o:messages>` ? If you absolutely need it inside a variablle you could also just use `<c:set>` rather than relying on the `message` attribute.

Comment: Because then I lose some of the handy attributes of `<o:messages ..>`.